# How to make data structure for a type that is not coverd by Schema.org?

Tags: data-structures, schema.org, structured-data

I am just starting to classify my webpage's content to get better result by Google and other search engines. But my type is not covered by any of the Schema.org types.

For example a part of my website includes articles that introduce the plants like trees, flowers, …

Each plant has these properties: Scientific Name, Latin Name, Image, Family, SubFamily, Genus, Division, Native, Class.

And also each plant has a sub type for "Caring Plant" like: Sun, Soil, Moisture, Temperature.

Please help me which type of Schema.org is good for me? If neither, how can I have my own structure type?

Answer (score 0):

If Schema.org offers no specific type for your domain, you can always use [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing).

Looking at its sub-types (as of [version 3.0](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v3.0): `Action`, `CreativeWork`, `Event`, `Intangible`, `Organization`, `Person`, `Place`, `Product`, and from extensions `MedicalEntity`), there doesn’t seem to be a more appropriate type (except `Product`, but only if you *offer* the plants).

However, such general types lack the properties you might need for your topic.

Unless you want to use a different vocabulary (there are most likely multiple vocabularies that can be used for plants, e.g., [The Plant Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_ontology)), possibly in addition to Schema.org, your only option is to [suggest a Schema.org extension](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html).